# Why should we not put end brackets on the same line?

Tags: coding-style, code-formatting

When writing block code in languages like C++ and Java, people usually argue over whether brackets at the end of a line should have their own line.

```
if (condition) {

if (condition)
{
```

However, I have never seen anyone even suggest the second format below. Are the following equivalent, and if so, why have I never seen the second? One possible reason is that it is much less common, but I see two brackets in a row fairly often.

```
if (condition) {
   //code
   if (condition) {
      //code
   }
}

if (condition) {
   //code
   if (condition) {
      //code
}  }
```

Comment: Lisp code tends to end up with a bunch of closing parenthesis all piled up together at the end of the line.

Comment: So many good answers, all with reasons why this is NOT a good idea. :)

Comment: A very simple reason not to use this might very well be that your automatic code formatter doesn’t support it (for example, clang-format doesn’t). If you don’t automatically format your code, you should start as soon as possible. It will make your life *so* much more comfortable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It's all about the indents

It's not really about the brackets, it's about indenting and vertical alignment.

**Not indented**

You *can* put brackets on the same line when indentation is not in play.

Example in lambda expression:

```
list.ForEach(  a => { a.Init(); a.DoSomething(); a.Complete(); });
```

Example when declaring an empty interface, like this one found in the .NET CLR:

```
interface IRequiresSessionState {}
```

**Simple indents**

But if you plan on indenting anything, the rule of identation says that stuff that starts and ends a code block should be similarly indented, and stuff inside the block should be one level deeper, like this:

```
void DoSomething() {
    Code();
}
```

The idea is that you can trace the beginning and end of the block by eyeballing it vertically.

You wouldn't do this:

```
    void DoSomething() {
        Code();
}
```

or this:

```
void DoSomething() {
    Code();
    }
```

because you can't use your eye to find the beginning that goes with the end.

**Double indents**

That being said, you CAN close two blocks on the same line, if you opened two blocks on the same line, like in this very common Javascript example:

```
document.ready(function() {
                 DoSomething();
              });
```

Or

```
while(flag) { for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
                 DoSomething();
            }};
```

...although frankly I don't think I'd ever use a construct like that one.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that the opposite brackets ended the blocks.

Comment: You see double bracket indents occasionally in some styles of Java to add an instance initializer to an anonymous subclass, eg: `... = new SomeContainer() {{ add(thing1); add(thing2); }};`

Comment: +1 as the key is about readability, not saving space / lines in the IDE.

Comment: I know a lot of people that do `or this:`; you can even find examples if you just scroll down some more replies.

Answer (score 6):

One reason I can think of is that putting the closing brackets on individual lines makes it easier to (un)comment the whole block using `//` without breaking the syntax.

Comment: Makes sense, though usually you'd use /* */ for that.

Comment: Usually you'd select the block and use a keyboard shortcut to have your editor turn it into a comment.  Whether the editor uses `//` or `/* */` depends on the editor, but in either case, it's easier to make the initial selection when you're selecting whole lines.

Answer (score 6):

You want to be able to tell statements apart and to see where a block/compound starts and where it ends. This is why Allman style is superior:

```
if (condition)
{
  // compound content
}
```

However, some people have grown used to old paper-saving K&R style:

```
if (condition) {
    // compound content
}
```

which makes it harder to see blocks because the opening and closing characters are not in the same column and it is harder to tell the condition apart from the block. But still you can see one statement. The opening parenthesis is sort of dysfunctional, just there after the condition because it needs to be present somewhere. But the closing one is nicely in line with the start of the statement.

Now this...

```
if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        // compound content
}   }
```

Both Allman and K&R disciples will agree this is just horrible. because you have no reference whatsoever that helps you seeing the statement blocks. It even looks like the last } belongs to the inner if statement, which it does not.

Comment: It isn't a paper-saving style so much as it is a field-of-view-saving style.  It has been known for several decades that programmer comprehension is essentially limited to what the programmer can see at one glance, without turning a listing page or scrolling a screen.  See Weinberg's "Psychology of Computer Programming" for more information.

Comment: I don't think Allman style is superior, as it doesn't clearly point out, that the block is conditional; the `if` above could as well be an unrelated statement and get easily overlooked, and the block just be an unconditional block.

Answer (score 2):

In this very specific case it leads to very misleading code, and misleading code is bad code. At first glance it looks like that first closing brace is for the outer `if` but it actually belongs to the inner `if`

Answer (score 0):

*(This answer takes the question in the spirit of 'why is this not discussed much' as opposed to 'why shouldn't you do it'.)*

The Wikipedia article on this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) shows two indentation styles (out of the nine listed) which place the closing brace after the last line of code (as opposed to on a line by itself):

Pico:

```
while (x == y)
{   something();
    somethingelse(); }
```

Lisp:

```
while (x == y) {
    something();
    somethingelse(); }
```

What you suggest appears to be the Lisp style.  However, I acknowledge that yours is a bit of a hybrid - the first brace is on a new line, but duplicate braces are collapsed.

The question of why you haven't seen much discussion about it is probably because people are generally in agreement that this is a bad thing!  There are some obvious reasons why this would cause problems (hard to comment-out, harder to read, etc.) and the ideological question of whether the start of the block is the brace or the statement that precedes it doesn't really apply to the closing brace (except, perhaps in a `do...while` loop), so there's much less to get heated about.

Comment: According to the current wikipedia entry, that is not, in fact, the Lisp style. They say the Lisp style would be to put the open curly half-indented before the first line of the block, not on the block header.

Comment: The article may have changed since I wrote this, but either way my main point is about the closing bracket, not the opening one, so I don't think this makes any material difference.

Answer (score 0):

There are three places in any block of code where you want to insert or delete a line: before the existing first line, between two existing lines, after the last existing line.

The second is easy.  The first and third are what dictate the position of the opening and closing brackets.  If the bracket is on the same line as the existing line of code, you're going to suffer, and, sooner or later, someone is going to screw it up.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it's all about human readability, since the machine doesn't give a rat's elbow one way or the other. And as far as humans are concerned, "it's all in the eye of the beholder", so there can't really be any unambiguously mathematically correct answer. But one answer is "standards", much the same way the QWERTY keyboard layout has become standard -- after a while, everybody gets comfortable enough with it.

But my particular style, take it or leave it, is somewhat context-dependent. For short blocks of code, I usually don't put the closing "**}**" on a separate line, e.g.,

```
if ( this ) {
  that1;
  that2; }
```

But for longer blocks

```
while ( this ) {
  that1;
  that2;
  etc;
  } /* --- end-of-while(this) --- */
```

not only do I put the closing "**}**" on a separate line, I label it with a comment designating its scope. (Personally, I hate that emacs-and-similar syntax highlighting that blinks the mating delimiter for you, but that's just me:).

So my personal take is that a carved-in-stone standard for this aspect of style is overkill. You look at the code you're writing, and try to write it in a style that will be most readable for the next poor slob who comes along and has to read and maintain it.